# Is there any way to make a method from an interface return a generic List<> using the DAO pattern?

Tags: java

I am working with the DAO pattern on Java, and I will use it to basically initialize and return lists of objects. So I want to make a method that, when overridden, returns a list of objects of any type that the class which implements the interface chooses.

Now the method "getAllItens()" returns a list of "Item" objects, and I don't want to create another interface just to initialize different types of objects.

```
public interface Dao
{
    //...
    public List<Item> getAllItens();
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use generics for that

```
public interface Dao<T>
{
    //...
    List<T> getAllItems();
    //...
}
```

and

```
class YourConcreteDao implements Dao<Person>
```

Comment: I suggest to rename the method to _findAll()_ so you can also add for example _findById_ and _findByStatus_, _findByTypeWithStatus_

Comment: The method return type should be List<? extends T> instead of List<T>

Answer (score -1):

If your are using Spring/Spring-boot you can also use [Spring Data Repositories](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/) for your DAO layer. That gives you a lot of functionality for free (like this kind of methods).

Comment: There is as saying in my country: If a grandma would have a mustashe, she would be a grandpa (not always true cuz come of them do have mustashe, but you should get the point :))